# psql denies access to file when using COPY FROM

Tags: postgresql, psql, csv

When I do this:

```
COPY "mytable" FROM '/my/file.csv' WITH DELIMITER AS ',' CSV;
```

On this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter 54819176 2011-07-21 13:17 file.csv
```

psql tells me this:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/my/file.csv" for reading: Permission denied
```

How can I read my file??  Thanks!

--- Update

It looks like something called `apparmor` is installed by default in Ubuntu.
Seems to have the same functionality as SELinux, mentioned in the comments.

--- Update

After removing `apparmor`, I still have the same problem.  `selinux` is not installed.

Regarding the comment below about access, the COPY FROM is being run from a superuser account (it gives a different error message if not) and the file permissions, copied above, I understand as "readable by everyone".

--- Update

I tried to get to the file under the `postgres` user.  It gets stuck at a particular place in the tree

`drwxr--r-- 6 peter peter 4096 2011-04-14 14:03 phm`

`postgres@dexter:/home/peter/PyPacks$ cd phm`

`bash: cd: phm: Permission denied`

I suppose I will just put the file somewhere else, but this is strange!

Comment: are you running SELinux or something like it?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux

Comment: In other words, SELinux is preventing access?

Comment: Have you got it installed (dpkg --get-selections | grep selinux)? If so, it might be.

Comment: There is a `libselinux1` installed.  Also, `semanage` is not installed.  So I don't really know where I stand.

Comment: "Files named in a COPY command are read or written directly by the server, not by the client application. Therefore, they must reside on or be accessible to the database server machine, not the client. They must be accessible to and readable or writable by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as), not the client. COPY naming a file is only allowed to database superusers, since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to access." (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: To stress Milen's point: is the file actually stored on the server where PostgreSQL is running?

Comment: If the file isn't on the database server, shouldn't that give you a "file not found" error rather than a  "permission denied" error? I'm thinking that the PostgreSQL user (the service account?) might not have permission to read that file.

Comment: @Pete Have you found a solution?

Comment: In case it is relevant, I was loading csv data from a fuse-mounted directory (storage bucket, mounted by non-postgres system account), and `ls -ld` said that the postgres user *should* have been allowed to read the contents, however when I switched to the postgres user, it was unable to read it and the permissions showed up as all `?`. Since the data is very large, copying it to the root device is not feasible. Since I'd had mysterious errors with fuse before I was able to narrow it down and fixed it by adding `-o allow_other` to the fuse mount command. Now it all works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> drwxr--r-- 6 peter peter 4096 2011-04-14 14:03 phm
>
> postgres@dexter:/home/peter/PyPacks$ cd phm
>
> bash: cd: phm: Permission denied
> ```

Directories need to be executable to be able to cd into them (or use files within them). All the sub-directory from `/` to the `/home/peter/PyPacks/phm` need to be executable by the user you want to use for this to work.

Try at least `chmod 711 phm` (which should give you `rwx--x--x`), or perhaps `chmod 755 phm` (`rwxr-xr-x`). `r` for directories is the ability to list their content, not to go into them (or use files/directories within them).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the `psql` command-line tool, you may use `\copy` instead of `copy`.

`\copy` opens the file and feeds the contents to the server, whereas `copy` tells the server the open the file itself and read it, which may be problematic permission-wise, or even impossible if client and server run on different machines with no file sharing in-between.

Under the hood, `\copy` is implemented as `COPY FROM stdin` and accepts the same options than the server-side `COPY`.

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463074/postgres-error-could-not-open-file-for-reading-permission-denied

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the user postgres must have the right to read the files and execute the directories. It also needs a restart of the PSQL server.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re on a Mac place the csv file on ‘/tmp’ directory. In this case, the file would be accessible by all users such as pgadmin.